# $f:(a \space b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $|f|$ is differentiable, then $f$ is differentiable or not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:(a\space b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and |f| is differentiable on $(a\space b)$. Then $f$ is differentiable or not?

Intuitively I am guessing it to be true and have tried to prove using the definition of differentiability but didn't succeed.

Comment: Here’s a hint. What special conditions would we need on $f$ for $|f|$ to be differentiable?

Comment: $f(x)$ has to be either non negative or non positive for every $x\in (a \space b)$ ,right?

Comment: and f has to be smooth as well

Comment: Not quite. What about a function like this (with $f(0) = 0$) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dgxsyrdhq3

Comment: I'm observing,  a linear function attending both +ve and -ve values can't be our f here. sin x , cos x type functions won't be our f here too .  I have to choose our f in a way so that |f| can't possess a peak point.

Comment: Did you look at the graph I posted? that function achieves positive and negative values, but has a differentiable absolute value. What’s special about that function that makes it work?

Comment: Actually, a better example of the phenomenon is $f(x) = x^3$. You may easily compute by force that $\frac{d}{dx} |x^3| = 3 x |x|$. What is special about $f(x) = x^3$?

Comment: Yes I have seen the graph you pasted. The tangent at x=0 for both the above mentioned functions is parallel to x axis. Or in other words the first derivative is zero .I am not able to see any other special property of these two, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to bed soon, so I’m going to just write up an answer here.

Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. In the comments, you suggested that if $|f(x)|$ is differentiable, then either $f \geq 0$ or $f \leq 0$ on all of $(a,b)$. This is not the case. Indeed, a counter example may be given by $f(x) = x^3$ on the interval $(-1,1)$. Here we clearly have that $f$ takes on positive and negative values, but we have that $|x^3|$ is differentiable with derivative $\frac{d}{dx} |x^3| = 3 x |x|$.

You are right though that the problem is “easier” in the case that $f$ is non-negative or non-positive. Indeed we may prove the following “easy” lemma.

**Lemma 1:** Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and $|f|$ be differentiable. If $x_0 \in (a,b)$ and $f(x_0) \neq 0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

**Proof:**
This easily follows from the fact that since $f(x_0) \neq 0$, there is a sub-interval $(c,d) \subseteq (a,b)$ containing $x_0$ on which $|f| = f$ or $|f| = -f$.

So the only place where something could go wrong is at the zeros of $f$. Looking at the $f(x)=x^3$, we notice that the derivative at $0$, we have $f(0) = 0$. Further, we see that $f’(0) = |f|’(0) = 0$. Maybe this is always the case. We prove the following lemma:

**Lemma 2:** Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and $|f|$ be differentiable. If $f(x_0) = 0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with $f’(x_0) = |f|’(x_0) = 0$.

**Proof:**
Looking at the difference quotients, we see:
$$\begin{align*} \frac{|f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)|}{h} & = \frac{|f(x_0 + h) |}{h} \\ & = \frac{ \big | |f(x_0 + h)| \big |} {h} \end{align*}$$
It immediately follows taking limits as $h \rightarrow 0$ that $f’(x_0)$ exists and $f’(x_0) = |f|’(x_0)$.

While not strictly necessary for your problem, it is also easy to see that if $|f|’(x_0) \neq 0$, then there is a point $x_1$ such that $|f(x_1)| < 0$, which cannot be the case. Thus $f’(x_0) = |f|’(x_0) = 0$.

Combining these two lemmas, we get the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. If $|f|$ is differentiable, than $f$ is differentiable as well.

Comment: I think your lemma 2 is correct, but only if you **first** Note that $|f|'(x_0)=0$ (the derivative has to appear **inside** your day expression with the difference quotient). The derivative has to be zero, since there is a global minimum of $|f|$ in $x_0$ (why?!).

Comment: It's a duplicate question.